# My elementary os is freezing very often, how can I identify and solve this problem?

Tags: release-loki

This mis my first attempt to use Elementary OS.
I am using a GIGABYTE GB-BXBT-1900 with 8GB of memory, as well as, a 240 GB solid state hard disk. It has frozen twice within the first hour of use. Once while browsing the internet and the second while familiarizing myself with the OS. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you run updates first thing after the install? If not, please do. Open AppCenter and go to the updates tab. If offered there, also install "intel-microcode". Reboot.

Comment: Having the same freezing situation and it is so frustrating. I realized that is happening since kernels are .112 and .113, I had changed to .112 and looks a little more stable compared to .113 but freezes the same. It was really fast and snappy and now is all buggy and frezzes, I can not have more that three tabs of browsers without having to reboot the system. Even though that would be Chrome but it is happening even with Epiphany.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the harsh "welcome" from the EOS. Anyway I would suggest to watch the system log for errors close to the seconds of the freeze (yes you need to write down the exact time when system freezes). Then try to search for the error. Maybe it will be descriptive enough to understand without search.
In my case the freezing was caused by faulty open source NVidia driver.

Comment: I'm using "System Logs", "Logs" or just "cat /var/log/syslog" (least favorite)

Answer (score 0):

It may do to the intel processor. I had similar experience with a laptop with intel processor. What I did was open the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"** 
with **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"**

Save it (CTRL+O)
Exit (CTRL+X)

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please include the why, what does this do?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem right after switching from windows.
Turns out that my laptop didn't have enough ram to run my stuff and Elementary OS only had ~1GB of swap allocated. This caused freezing problems.

**So the solution was to increase swap size.** Here are the commands I used:

1. create a size 16G file called swapfile in /  
   `sudo fallocate -l 16G /swapfile`
2. set the file as swap space 
   `sudo mkswap /swapfile`
3. set the swap file as permanent (or it will disappear after reboot) 
   `echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab`

After this we can use commands like `htop` to see if swap is increased.